# How to append date in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

How does one append the date in R Markdown to include say both the date created and the date last rendered  to be on two separate lines. For example, I'd like the output on the first page to be:

Created on: October 21, 2018
Last Updated on: October 22, 2018

The Code I'm using is:

```
date: "Created on October 21, 2018"  #note two blank spaces before the next line
'`r paste("Last Updated on: ",format(Sys.Date(),"%B %d,%Y"))`'
```

Answer (score 4):

Keep it simpler -- just put the *fixed* text inside the `paste()` function. In other words, make it for example

```
date: '`r paste("First created on Oct 01, 2018. Updated on", Sys.Date())`'
```

which would work as follows. You have all the control you need inside the 
`paste()`, so `format(Sys.Date(), "%b %d, %Y")` creates `Oct 21, 2018`.

[image]